# Присоединить токен ко всем ajax запросам автоматически в AngularJS

Tags: token, csrf, angularjs, javascript

Всем привет. Мне нужно, чтобы при всех запросах к ним присоединялся токен, как это сделать, я понял:

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', [], function ($httpProvider) {

    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';

$httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = [function(data) {

    data.token = '123';
    return angular.isObject(data) && String(data) !== '[object File]' ? param(data) : data;

}];
```

И такая схема даже работает, он действительно ко всем запросам добавляет token, но из консоли никак не пропадает ошибка:

```
 TypeError: Cannot set property 'token' of undefined at       $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest
```

Я понимаю, что это потому что data заранее не указан как массив, но как мне это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить в код такую конструкцию:

```
if (data === undefined) {
    data = {};
}

data.token = '123';
```